# Run command through a c# socket

Tags: c#, wpf, sockets

I'm writing a c# application which connects to a remote server for doing stuff.
I'm already able to copy files to the client, and what I wish to do now, after I finished copying all the files is send a "command signal" through my Socket, and make the client run it.

Just for the example, this is what I wish to do:

```
string cmD = @"\\192.168.0.1\\cmd";
byte[] clientData = new byte[8000];
clientData = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(cmD);
clientSock.Send(clientData);
```

Let's assume that clientSock is the static Socket connected to my server.
In this case, I would like to run "cmd" on the client side.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sure, add the code to the client side which will run that command. (nb: you should use psexec instead, from Sysinternals, to do this in a secure fashion).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the end, you have not asked anything. Could you please detail what exactly would you like to ask?

Anyway, I guess you are trying to run a command in the remote server so, you will have to implement it in your C# server. To run commands, you can use `Process::Start()` method. Good luck!

Cheers,

Comment: I am replying telling him to Use Process::Start().

Comment: Ok, The thing is I don't have a client app. I'm connecting to the remote server without any involvement of the remote computer. So, I don't have a code on the client side.. Now if I write Process::Start() and send, for example, "cmd" to it, will it run the command line on the remote? Thanks again, Idan.

Comment: Of course not, you can not decide what to run in the remote computer without implementing an application on there that interprets the commands and executes it.